# Ignore sub-projects in gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle multi-project and I'm trying to create a task into root build.gradle file, 
I need to run that task just once after the checkout or every-time I need to generate the jars file(from an war) which the project depend on. 
  
The problem is that when I run "gradle myTask", gradle try to compile all the projects that are in the file setting.gradle but as I don't have yet the jars it fails.

Is there a way to run a task ignoring setting.gradle?

I have tried "gradle -c fake-setting.gradle myTask" and it works perfectly but I hope there is a better way to do it...

```
task postCheckout << { 
   println "<<<<<< postCheckout" 
   delete fileTree(dir: "${rootProject.projectDir}/libs/fineos", include: ".") 
   copy{ 
      from zipTree("${rootProject.projectDir}/fineos-war/fineos6/fineos.war/") 
      include "WEB-INF/lib/*.jar" 
      eachFile { fcp-> fcp.path = fcp.name } 
      into "${rootProject.projectDir}/libs/fineos" includeEmptyDirs = false 
   } 
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a need to ignore subprojects. Gradle won't try to compile all projects unless the root project's `myTask` task depends on them, or each project has a task named `myTask` that depends on the project's compiled output.

Comment: The thing is that in the sub-projects I have the dependences to the jar that myTask have to put in a folder where all the projects look for...  MyTask is only in the root project...

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong with the build. Perhaps the `myTask` task isn't declared correctly. Gradle will only compile the subprojects if this is necessary for executing `myTask`.

Comment: task postCheckout << { 

        println "<<<<<<    postCheckout" 
        
        delete fileTree(dir: "${rootProject.projectDir}/libs/fineos", include: "*.*")   
        copy{ 
                from zipTree("${rootProject.projectDir}/fineos-war/fineos6/fineos.war/") 
                include "WEB-INF/lib/*.jar" 
                        
                eachFile { fcp-> 
                        fcp.path = fcp.name 
                } 
                into "${rootProject.projectDir}/libs/fineos" 
                includeEmptyDirs = false 
        } 
}

Comment: Please add that to the original question. It doesn't belong in a comment.

Comment: Sorry... I fixed the problem with a post from you Peter ... The problem was that gradle look for a setting.gradle end try to evaluate the sub-projects matching the dependences like runtime: 'someJar' and fail because can't find them... The solution is to move that task in a different gradle file for example mybuild.gradle and run "gradle -b mybuild.gradle myTask" in this case gradle don't look at setting.gradle as default behaviour.

Comment: Gradle won't resolve dependencies unless they are actually used. `gradle -b` is just a workaround for some bug in your build script(s).